# Share redux store between web, mobile app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to share redux between web, mobile according to this post https://medium.com/kuralabs-engineering/reactive-core-architecture-for-react-native-and-react-applications-d590daf4ef8a Here I have a problem, how should I handle Ajax requests both for web, mobile (react native) apps? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I really like the approach of epics using [*Redux Observable*](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable). This allows you to dispatch an action in the Redux store so a side-effect can happen using epics. Since actions are DTOs, they are already abstracted. You can define an HTTP_ACTION like so:

```
{
  type: 'HTTP_REQUEST',
  payload: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/some-url',
    body: {
      id: 'some-id'
    },
    responseAction: 'HTTP_REQUEST_COMPLETED'  // Some unique action type here that will be caught by a reducer.
  }
}
```

This approach has many advantages. It decouples the action creator from any side-effect. This makes them easy to test. It also puts all side-effects in one part of the app: The epics. This is because *Redux Observable* replaces all other side-effect middlewares in Redux (like redux-thunk or redux-promise). This allows you to replace the epics based on something platform-specific.

The disadvantages are that you need to learn rx-js, which can be somewhat hard. Testing the epics is also a bit complex, but totally feasible.

Obviously, there are other solutions available. But you should at least look into this one to see if it works for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll take a look

Comment: redux sagas would be an alternative, with requiring rx, though rx is awesome.